# IIS 7.5 Changes don't take effect until server restart

Tags: iis

I've been setting up a new web server and I'm using IIS 7.5  and I've noticed that when I add or make changes to websites, the changes don't take effect until I restart the entire server.  I've tried restarting the sites from within IIS, I've tried restarting the IIS service (W3SVC), but short of that I'm not sure what else to try..I don't think I should have to restart the entire server to get the changes to take effect.   Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: changes as in updating a .asp file or something, or changes as in modifying site settings in the IIS manager?

Comment: Some changes do require a reboot. So unless you explicitly state which change you feel inconvenient and unreasonable I don't think this question is valid.

Comment: Wow Lex, thats sort of a rude way of responding to a question.  Sorry, I thought I was being clear in my question, but I'll try to add more context.  I'm referring to making changes in IIS manager, If I go in and add or remove an alias for example, and sometimes when I add a site to IIS manager, the alias or new site doesn't work until I restart the server.  I would think that restarting the W3SVC service would be sufficient.  I guess I can accept that some changes may require a reboot, but downtime like that seems excessive.